# Exported variable is still not visible after exporting

Tags: perl, scope, package, exporter

I am working on a simple Perl module to create and validate musical notes and to find enharmonically equivalent notes. I am storing an array reference containing all valid notes in a module and then exporting it so the `Note.pm` module can see which notes are valid and check against the list when it goes to create a `Note` object.

The problem is, no matter what I try the Exported `$VALID_NOTES` array reference is not visible in `Note.pm`! I've read through the documentation on [`Exporter`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) about a thousand times and looked back at tons of my old Perl modules that use `Exporter` and I just cannot figure out what is wrong here...

Here is the code:

**test.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Music;

my $m = Music->new();

my $note = $m->note('C');

print $note;
```

**Music.pm**

```
package Music;

use Moose;
use Note;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw($VALID_NOTES);

no warnings 'qw';

# Valid notes
# Enharmonic notes are in preferred (most common) order:
#     Natural -> Sharp -> Flat -> Double Sharp -> Double Flat
our $VALID_NOTES = [
    [ qw(C B#        Dbb) ],
    [ qw(  C# Db B##    ) ],
    [ qw(D       C## Ebb) ],
    [ qw(  D# Eb     Fbb) ],
    [ qw(E    Fb D##    ) ],
    [ qw(F E#        Gbb) ],
    [ qw(  F# Gb E##    ) ],
    [ qw(G       F## Abb) ],
    [ qw(  G# Ab        ) ],
    [ qw(A       G## Bbb) ],
    [ qw(  A# Bb     Cbb) ],
    [ qw(B    Cb A##    ) ],
];

sub note {
    my $self = shift;
    my $name = shift;
    return Note->new(name => $name);
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

**Note.pm**

```
package Note;

use Moose;
use Music qw($VALID_NOTES);
use experimental 'smartmatch';

has 'name'  => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1);
has 'index' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Int', lazy => 1, builder => '_get_index');

# Overload stringification
use overload fallback => 1, '""' => sub { shift->name() };

sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;
    if (!grep { $self ~~ @{$VALID_NOTES->[$_]} } 0..$#{$VALID_NOTES}) {
        die "Invalid note: '$self'\n";
    }
}

sub _get_index {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($index) = grep { $self ~~ @{$VALID_NOTES->[$_]} } 0..$#{$VALID_NOTES};
    return $index;
}

sub enharmonic_notes {
    my $self = shift;
    my $index = $self->index();
    return map { Note->new($_) } @{$VALID_NOTES->[$index]};
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

When I run the code I get this output:

```
Global symbol "$VALID_NOTES" requires explicit package name at Note.pm line 15.
Global symbol "$VALID_NOTES" requires explicit package name at Note.pm line 15.
Global symbol "$VALID_NOTES" requires explicit package name at Note.pm line 22.
Global symbol "$VALID_NOTES" requires explicit package name at Note.pm line 22.
Global symbol "$VALID_NOTES" requires explicit package name at Note.pm line 29.
```

Comment: Answered [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=778639). Personally, I'd move `$VALID_NOTES` into Note where it belongs. You can always import it into Music and re-export it from Music.

Comment: Please don't use the smartmatch experimental feature; it will be removed from Perl or changed in a backwards incompatible manner.

Comment: Mixing Moose and Exporter? I'd rather not.

Comment: @choroba, wut? Nothing wrong with that!

Comment: @ikegami, is there another clean way to search an array in a single line like this? Searching arrays of arrays gets rather complicated without smart-match.

Comment: @ikegami: With an OO module, I'd rather use a package method to return the structure.

Comment: @choroba, Why would you want to disguise a constant as a method!

Comment: @tjwrona1992, A `grep` can be used instead of `~~` here. If you need to hide the `grep`, you can use a sub instead of an experimental operator. That said, I would build a lookup hash from `$VALID_NOTES`.

Comment: @ikegami: Well, it's much better to disguise it as a variable :-)

Comment: @choroba, Oh, I didn't notice. I would use actual constant instead of var.

Comment: good to note, I will change it to an actual constant

Comment: @ikegami, quick follow-up question. should I `use constant` or `use ReadOnly` to deal with constant variables?

Comment: Personally, I'd use `constant` and not worry about the fact that it's not actually constant. If you want to go all the way, that's fine too.

Comment: Actually I just tried `constant` and it doesn't seem to like when I try to dereference a constant array ref, the fact that `ReadOnly` keeps the sigil makes regular syntax work better.

Comment: `${ +CONSTANT }[ ]` because `${ CONSTANT }[ ]` means `$CONSTANT[ ]`

Comment: Thanks, good to know! I will stick with `ReadOnly` though because it makes the variable deeply constant and I already figured out how to get it to work. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Music.pm`, populate the `@EXPORT_OK` in a BEGIN block *before* loading `Note`:

```
package Music;
use Moose;
our @EXPORT_OK;
BEGIN { @EXPORT_OK = qw($VALID_NOTES) }
use Exporter qw(import);
use Note;
```

Comment: I'm getting `C` as the output.

Comment: interesting... I literally just copied and pasted it to make sure i didn't make a mistake and it's still failing for me.

Comment: Had a typo somewhere else! it works. Thanks. I think I might move the variable into the "Notes" module altogether to eliminate the problem entirely though.